# Single Value Binding

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-controls, onclientclick

The intent is to append the javascript code within the OnClientClick event to pass in the value of SearchIDTextbox as the ID parameter. If I hard code "22" for ???? the
function runs properly. I thinK I need to make ???? a single value bind expression 
but I'm having trouble setting up the code.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="PremiumUserImageButton" Width="40px" OnClientClick="return clientClickEvent('AdvancedSearch.aspx?ID= ???? )" CausesValidation="False" ImageUrl="~/Images/Premium.gif" runat="server" />
```

Tried This no luck!

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="PremiumUserImageButton"  Width="40px" OnClientClick="return clientClickEvent('AdvancedSearch.aspx?ID='<%# GetID() %>'" CausesValidation="False" ImageUrl="~/Images/Premium.gif" runat="server" />
```

Comment: need to first get the value of `searchTextbox` by `document.getelementbyid` method in javascript and assign it to the function as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have put extra apostrophe. As well as there is no any bracket close for the javascript function.

Please replace your code with below code.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="PremiumUserImageButton"  Width="40px" OnClientClick="return clientClickEvent('AdvancedSearch.aspx?ID=<%# GetID() %>');" CausesValidation="False" ImageUrl="~/Images/Premium.gif" runat="server" />
```

You can also check this tag in firebug which is firefox best Add on.

Hope this will help you.